# Is there anyway to dismiss a limit break and not use it?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I'm replaying FFVII and loving it, however sometimes when trying to pull off a morph (such as getting ribbon in the battle square) I don't actually want to do a limit break when it pops.

Is there anyway (during battle - I know about changing break level outside of battle) of dismissing a limit break so that you don't use it and instead do the 'normal attack' - which in this case would be 4x cut?

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, though definitely related. This question seems to be indicating they just want to waste it, rather than save it.

Comment: Yup - I want to completely annul the limit break, not use it and have a 'normal' attack instead. The duplicate DOES have the answer I want, but it's voted 0 and not accepted as the answer. Should I still accept as a duplicate?

Comment: Related is closer than dupe, but still very close.

Comment: There is no way i know of to waste one infight. Out of fight you may switch the limitlevel (for example from 4 to 3 and back) to reset the bar to 0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although not possible in battle, and only possible outside of battle once the character has unlocked Limit level 2.

Once outside the battle you can go to the Main Menu -> Limit and change the Limit level you wish your character to use, doing so will remove all Limit gauge build up including 100% flashing.